# GLTF obj color theme in Threebox

Tags: three.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I insert a GLTF object in mapbox by threebox with the following codes. The appearance of the obj looks dark. Any options is available to change the color theme of the GLTF object?

```
     var options = {
              obj: './models/WMK-CSC-ALL-XX-XX-00_0.gltf',
              mtl: './models/WMK-CSC-ALL-XX-XX-00_0.bin', 
              type: 'gltf',
              scale: 1,
              units: 'meters',
              rotation: { x: 90, y: 120, z: 0 }, 
              anchor: 'center'
        }

      tb.loadObj(options, function (model) {
                let bldg = model.setCoords(origin3);
                tb.add(bldg);
        })
```

[image: Image Output in Web]

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using [Threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox), first of all your init Params are wrong, instead of:
`mtl: './models/WMK-CSC-ALL-XX-XX-00_0.bin'`
It should be:
`bin: './models/WMK-CSC-ALL-XX-XX-00_0.bin'`

If you are initializing Threebox properly with default lights:

```js
window.tb = new Threebox(
    map,
    map.getCanvas().getContext('webgl'), //get the context from the map canvas
    { defaultLights: true }
);
```

it should be well illuminated with an `AmbientLight` and two `DirectionalLight`.
I’m maintaining the latest version of [threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox) so feel free to open an issue there if this doesn’t solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your inputs. I added the two "DirectionalLight" to resolve the issue.

```
onAdd: function (map, mbxContext) {

                    tb.altitudeStep = 1;

                    //// initialize geometry and material of our cube object
                    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30, 60, 120);

                    // create two three.js lights to illuminate the model
                    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
                    directionalLight.position.set(0, -70, 100).normalize();
                    tb.scene.add(directionalLight);
                     
                    var directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
                    directionalLight2.position.set(0, 70, 100).normalize();
                    tb.scene.add(directionalLight2);
                    ....
                    ....
```

Comment: Good if that solves your issues, but did you change de init params to load properly the bin file?

Comment: Default parameter (_defaultLights: true_ ) is used already but it doesn't take the effect.

Comment: I meant this `bin: './models/WMK-CSC-ALL-XX-XX-00_0.bin' ` to load properly the bin file of your gltf  model instead of what you are using `mtl: ...` which is only for obj/mtl models not valid for gltf models

Comment: If you can share the model I’d love to know what’s wrong with it and the default lights

Comment: Here is the model. Thanks. [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vbajWcOvyysOnicDL-eZNm3ISxlUYuKI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226469/discussion-between-user17817-and-jscastro).